# matching game with light or buzzer

Tags: piezo-buzzer

My students made a matching game that matches states with governors. We can make it light up if they get the question right. How do we make it sound a buzzer when the answer is wrong?

Comment: This question is **so vague**. You need to provide more information about your project.

Comment: Show the schematic of how the matching is done, and of what happens if you've got it right.

Comment: Huh?  You can't see for yourself we don't know what you think a "matching game" is, what the states are, what a "governor" is, and what is supposed to light up!?

Comment: Matching game (http://pack152.net/Webelos/WebelosActivityBadges/Engineer/QuizBoard.htm)

Comment: @OlinLathrop The states are those territories that you live in (for you Massachusetts), governors are the chief executives of each state (for you Deval Patrick), and a matching game is where you match the governor with the state. I actually think that that was the most detailed part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've got a battery, light and test probes connected in series and the "quiz" has wires connecting the question and correct answer.  This circuit works because when you have the right answer, the circuit is completed and when you have the wrong answer nothing happens.

For what you are asking for, the circuit needs some way to tell the difference between a wrong answer (probes in the wrong spot) and no answer (probes not connected to anything).

You might try this circuit which solves this problem by adding a "test" switch.  You would use the same quiz board and then after attaching the test probes, push the test switch.  If the user is correct the light turns on.  If they are wrong, the buzzer sounds.[image]

The circuit uses a relay to select which device to activate.  When the correct answer is selected, the battery, relay coil circuit is completed and the relay connects terminals 6 and 10.  If an incorrect answer is selected, the relay coil isn't energized and the relay connects terminals 6 and 1.  Pressing the test switch causes either the buzzer or lamp circuit to be energized by the battery.

In terms of component selection, I'd suggest using a 9V battery and so you'd need a 9Vdc relay, 9V buzzer and 9V lamp.

Comment: I think it should work without requiring a "test" button: match the two and get your result.

Comment: @stevenvh well in this case I like the test button; it prevents you from being excessively notified of the mistake :)

Comment: @clabacchio - You wouldn't be excessively notified. As long as you're just holding the probes nothing should happen. Only when you connect a governor and a state you should either hear the buzzer or see the lamp go on.

Comment: @stevenvh I agree that not having the test button would be more desirable; however, this requirement will make the circuit more complicated and likely well beyond the OP's capabilities.  This circuit is readily constructable (and potentially understandable) by students.

Answer (score 0):

How about designing a relaxation oscillator which makes no noise and uses minimal current when no current is injected into a control input, and otherwise output a tone whose frequency is proportional to the injected current?  Tie all of the states to a common bus bar via moderately-value resistors (e.g. 10K or so), and tie one of the probes to the supply with a similar resistor.  Tie the other probe to the control input of the oscillator via another similar resistor.

When the supply probe is on the same state as the control-input probe, the current will have to flow through two resistors.  When it's on a different state, the current will have to flow through four resistors.  When the current flows through more resistors, the oscillator will produce a lower tone than it would if it were flowing through fewer.